# Google Cloud SQL に最適な GUI アプリケーションは？

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, google-cloud, google-app-engine, libreoffice

Google Cloud Platform > Cloud SQL > MySQL 第 2 世代インスタンス
を作成しました。

このインスタンスにある DB に、私の Mac から、
Microsoft Access (MacOS 版がありません) や
LibreOffice Base (Mac 版はありますが不安定なところがあり、日本語フォーラム等も充実しているとは言いづらいです)
などのような、日本語 & GUI ベースのアプリケーションで接続したいです。

特に、下記の事を 日本語 & GUI で行いたいです (要するに何でもじゃないか、と言われそうですが)。

1. 下記の事を日本語で質問したい

   1. 技術文書を閲覧する
   2. 行き詰まった時にフォーラム等で質問する
2. 下記の事を GUI で行いたい

   1. フィールドのプロパティの設定
   2. クエリの作成
   3. フォームの作成
   4. リレーション図の閲覧

つきましては、上記の 2 つのアプリケーション以外で、
おすすめのアプリケーションや開発環境がありましたらお教え願います。

月に何万円も支払わなければならないアプリケーションや、
買い切りでも 15 万円を超えるようなものは
選択の対象外とさせてください。

Google App Maker も選択肢に入れておりますが、 まだ使い始めで、
使い勝手の把握はおろか、当該 DB への接続もできておりません。
しかし、App Maker がおすすめという事でしたらその旨おっしゃっていただきたく思います。

(不案内のため意味不明の部分があればご指摘願います)

Answer (score 1):

MS Accessのようなフォームを作成したい場合、選択肢が減りそうです。

> 3. フォームの作成

VMWareなどの仮想化ソフトとWindows+MS Accessの利用が一番便利かもしれません。
(CPUは食いますが、Macでもシームレスに操作できると思います。)

Comment: MS Access には慣れているので一番良いのですが、私の Mac は MacBook (2017) なので、VirtualBox で Windows を走らせてみた限りでは厳しいです (CPU よりもメモリが 8 G なので)。VirtualBox よりも Parallels のの方が軽いと聞きますがまだ試しておりません。Access を使うなら MacBook Pro に変えるしか無いかもしれません…。しかし、ありがとうございます。

Comment: ご報告申し上げます。Parallels の仮想化ソフト上で MS Access 2016 を走らせてみたところ、MacBook でもかなり軽く動きます (具体的には、メモリが足りなくなりません) 。しばらく、この環境をメインにしてみたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

データベースの管理は、通常のMySQLと変わりはないので、`MySQL Workbench`又は`phpMyAdmin`を使えばGUIで管理ができます。ただし、`phpMyAdmin`の場合Macにインストールしてリモートでアクセスする必要があります。

`Access`及び`LibreOffice Base`の他に`Excel`からも接続が可能です。`Excel`の場合MySQLからデータを取ってきて処理をするのはODBCドライバをインストールすればウィザードで可能なので簡単にできます。Mac版も有料ですがODBCドライバがあるようです。一方、`Excel`からMySQLにデータを入れるのは結構難しいので、自分は、`Python`の`Pandas`で`Excel`のファイルを読み込んでから`Python`で処理をしています。これもMacで動作するのですがGUIでないので条件を満たさないです。`Excel`に`Python`が搭載されると嬉しいのですが何時になるかわかりません。

Macには、`Access`に近いソフトとして`FileMaker Pro Advanced`があります。MySQLに対応しているし評価版があるので一度試してみたらどうでしょうか。ただし、業務用のソフトに関しては、Windowsが圧倒的に強いので、Windowsで`Access`を使うようなサポートは期待できないと思います。

また、`LAMP`といわれたPHP製のWebアプリケーションがMySQLを使用しています。例えば、ブログを作る場合に使用する`WordPress`がMySQLを使っています。`WordPress`にはプラグインが豊富にあるので、フォームを作ろうという場合に用途によっては意外と使えるかもしれません。また、Web系には多くのアプリケーションがあるのでもう少し目的をはっきりさせれば使えるものが結構あると思います。ただし、HTMLとCSS でデザインをしていくので`MS Access`に慣れている場合は難しいかもしれませんが、最近は多くのアプリがWebになってきているのは、Webの方が結構作りやすいということもあるので検討してみたらと思います。

Comment: MySQL Workbench は何となく有料版 (Standard でも月当たり 2 万円) でないと使えないと思っていたのですが、違うようですね (情報が英語なので面倒で調べていませんでした) 。試してみます (ただしネット上の方々に日本語で助けを求められるかがまだ少し心配です) 。LibreOffice Base もネット上に日本語の大きなコミュニティがあれば良いのですが見つかりません。Mac 上で動く Access に近いソフトは FileMaker Pro Advanced だが

Comment: コメント編集が間に合いませんでした。MySQL Workbench は何となく有料版 (Standard でも月当たり 2 万円) でないと使えないと思っていたのですが、違うようですね (情報が英語なので面倒で調べていませんでした) 。試してみます (ただしネット上の方々に日本語で助けを求められるかがまだ少し心配です) 。LibreOffice Base もネット上に日本語の大きなコミュニティがあれば良いのですが見つかりません。Mac 上で動く Access に近いソフトは FileMaker Pro Advanced だがコミュニティのサポートは期待できないとのこと。残念です。コミュニティ等のサポートは私にとって必須ですので…。Web アプリを使う場合でも、私が求めているのは MS Access ライクな使い勝手であり (漠然としすぎていますか？) 、特にやりたいのは、非常に大きなデータ (テーブル) に対して非定型的で複雑な (GUI で行うにしては、ですが) 分析を繰り返し考えては実行する事ですので、できるだけクライアント PC 内で行わなければ厳しいのではないか (処理完了の待ち時間ばかりになるのではないか) と推測しているため、考えていませんでした。図々しいですが、Web アプリで Access ライクな使い方ができるものがあればお教え願いたいです。

Comment: 汎用的な使用であれば、データビジュアライゼーションが中心になりますが、Google データスタジオを使ってみたらどうですか。それからマイクロソフトのExcelとPowerBIの併用という方法もあります。
業務系以外ではデータ分析には、Excelを使うか、RかPythonを使うことが殆どです。Excelでもかなりのことはできるし、RもPythonもどちらかというとAccessライクではなくてExcelライクな使い方なのでのExcelの活用を考えた方がいいと思います。

Comment: Googleデータスタジオは知りませんでした。ざっと調べたところ、データの視覚化が主な目的のようで、少し違うかなと、今のところは考えております。私のやりたいこととしては、巨大で多数のデータソースを、クエリを複雑に組み合わせて、ソース内の値の規則性を探る、というような事ですので。Python は勉強したいと思っておりますので、Excel と Python の組み合わせでパワフルなシステムが組めるということであれば、良いかもしれません。試してみます。もし、Excel * Python で作るということになったら、また Stack Overflow で質問することになると思いますので、ご縁がありましたらまたご助力願えればと思います。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

だいぶ以前のスレッドに反応させていただき恐れ入りますが……

> FileMaker Pro Advanced だがコミュニティのサポートは期待できないとのこと。残念です。コミュニティ等のサポートは私にとって必須ですので…。

こちらについては、決してそんなことはありません、ということだけ補足させてください。
公式でのサポートはありますし、また、長年のユーザーが多いのでコミュニティも存在しています。

たとえば以下は、私の主催している Discord でのコミュニティになります。
チャット上で気軽に質問することも可能になっていますので、ご参考まで。

- FileMaker Casual ( 招待リンク https://discord.gg/PWWcYK8 )

なお、最初のご要望について FileMaker Pro で対応できるのは以下の通りです。

- フィールドのプロパティの設定

⇒こちらは限定的に可能です。

- クエリの作成

⇒こちらは独自のスクリプト等を作成することでおこなえます。

- フォームの作成

⇒こちらは可能です。

- リレーション図の閲覧

⇒こちらは FileMaker Pro 上で描き直すことで可能となります。